# Search results - convert webElement list into string and return true if some string is available in that list

Tags: java, selenium

I want to create a method which will be getting list of webelements by xpath, convert it to a string list and then check if searched word is present in that string list.

I've tried below code:

```
public void verifySearchResult () {

    List<WebElement> lst=ldriver.findElements(By.xpath(productNames));
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(WebElement e : lst)
    {
        strings.add(e.getText());
        System.out.println(strings);

    }
    if (strings.contains("shirt"))
    {
        System.out.println("OK");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("NO OK");
    }


}
```

The `System.out.println()` method returns:

```
Printed Chiffon Dress, Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts, Blouse, Printed Summer Dress, Printed Dress, Printed Summer Dress, Printed Dress, Printed Summer Dress, Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts
```

Result of `if, else` loop is NO OK. If i use .contains method, whole product string like "Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts" returns True.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood, you want to know when any of the web elements text contains the word *shirt*. The following method will return true for:

- Printed Chiffon Dress
- Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts

because of `Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts` and false for:

- Printed Summer Dress
- Printed Dress

```java
public boolean verifySearchResult () {
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath(productNames));
    for(WebElement e : list) {
        if (e.getText().contains("shirt")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use the xpath to achieve this rather iterating through the list and wasting the resources.

```
public boolean verifySearchResult (String productNames,String product_partial_text) {

    int matchingProducts=ldriver.findElements(By.xpath(productNames + "[contains(.,'" + product_partial_text + "')]")).size();

    if (matchingProducts>=1)
    {
        System.out.println("OK");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("NO OK");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions are great. I just want to show OP how to do it with `Streams API`

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath(productNames)).stream().map(x -> x.getText()).anyMatch(x.equals("shirt"));
```

The above code will get `List<WebElement>`, create `Stream` of it. 
The `map` method will change the type of list from `WebElement` to `String` based on `getText()` method.

Then, we write a `Predicate` if ANY of the `String` in the list matches word `shirt`.

The whole line returns `true` or `false`